# repeat image but number don't repeat (ascending count)

Tags: graphics, number

i want to use same icon, repeat image but number (\dataNo) need to increase

My current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,14pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=0.0cm,right=0cm,top=0.0cm,bottom=0.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{repeatcount}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}

\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3}%
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%
}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.tex}
No|Name
1|AAA
2|BCA
3|DXY
4|AAA4
5|BCA5
6|DXY6
7|AAA7
8|BCA8
9|DXY9
10|XYA
11|AAA
12|BCA
13|DXY
14|AAA4
15|BCA5
16|DXY6
17|AAA7
18|BCA8
19|DXY9
\end{filecontents}
 
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data1}{data1.tex}

\begin{document}
 \pagestyle{empty}%
    \noindent
\repeatthis{2}{%
\DTLforeach{data1}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
%\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.1\textwidth}
  \vspace{1.0cm}
  ~\\
\begin{center}  
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  
   {\Huge \dataNo}
     \linebreak
\end{center}
\end{minipage}\quad%
}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please see image and help
Number (\dataNo) = 1,2,..8,9, 10,11...20
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is there, just overflowing outside the page. I added #20 and changed the geometry a bit (right margin).

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape, left=0.0cm,right=5cm,top=0.0cm,bottom=0.0cm]{geometry}% changed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{repeatcount}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}
    
\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3}%
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%    
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data1.csv}
    No|Name
    1|AAA
    2|BCA
    3|DXY
    4|AAA4
    5|BCA5
    6|DXY6
    7|AAA7
    8|BCA8
    9|DXY9
    10|XYA
    11|AAA
    12|BCA
    13|DXY
    14|AAA4
    15|BCA5
    16|DXY6
    17|AAA7
    18|BCA8
    19|DXY9
    20|XXY9
\end{filecontents}

\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data1}{data1.csv}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \noindent
    \repeatthis{2}{%
        \DTLforeach{data1}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
            \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
                %\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.1\textwidth}
                \vspace{1.0cm}
                ~\\
                \begin{center}  
                    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
                    
                    {\Huge \dataNo}
                    \linebreak
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}\quad%
        }%
    }
    
\end{document}
```