# Remove border page

Tags: border

how can i remove border in allpage?

[image]
Thank you

Original Code: [repeat image but number don't repeat (ascending count)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635856/repeat-image-but-number-dont-repeat-ascending-count/635869#635869)

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,left=0.0cm,right=5cm,top=0.0cm,bottom=0.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{repeatcount}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}

\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3}%
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%    
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data1.csv}
    No|Name
    1|AAA
    2|BCA
    3|DXY
    4|AAA4
    5|BCA5
    6|DXY6
    7|AAA7
    8|BCA8
    9|DXY9
    10|XYA
    11|AAA
    12|BCA
    13|DXY
    14|AAA4
    15|BCA5
    16|DXY6
    17|AAA7
    18|BCA8
    19|DXY9
    20|XXY9
\end{filecontents}

\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data1}{data1.csv}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \noindent
    \repeatthis{2}{%
        \DTLforeach{data1}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
            \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
                %\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.1\textwidth}
                \vspace{1.0cm}
                ~\\
                \begin{center}  
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
                    
                    {\Huge \dataNo}
                    \linebreak
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}\quad%
        }%
    }
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to comment or delete the line:

```
\usepackage{showframe}
```