# add thin border for (image and number)

Tags: graphics, border

I have layout (icon and number).

Now i want to add very thin border for each (icon and number) and i used frame but don't luck.

[image]

```
               \frame{ 
                  \begin{center}  
                     \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
                     {\Huge \dataNo}
                    \linebreak
                  \end{center}
                }
```

My current code: [Remove border page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635871/remove-border-page/635873#635873)

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=0.0cm,right=5cm,top=0.0cm,bottom=0.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{repeatcount}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}

\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3}%
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%    
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data1.csv}
    No|Name
    1|AAA
    2|BCA
    3|DXY
    4|AAA4
    5|BCA5
    6|DXY6
    7|AAA7
    8|BCA8
    9|DXY9
    10|XYA
    11|AAA
    12|BCA
    13|DXY
    14|AAA4
    15|BCA5
    16|DXY6
    17|AAA7
    18|BCA8
    19|DXY9
    20|XXY9
\end{filecontents}

\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data1}{data1.csv}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \noindent
    \repeatthis{2}{%
        \DTLforeach{data1}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
        
            \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
                %\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.1\textwidth}
                \vspace{1.0cm}
                ~\\
                \frame{ 
                \begin{center}  
                  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
                  {\Huge \dataNo}
                    \linebreak
                \end{center}
                }
            \end{minipage}\quad%
            
        }%
    }
    
\end{document}
```

My desired result

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. The `\fbox` encapsulates the minipage.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=0.0cm]{geometry}% changed
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{repeatcount}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}

\newcommand{\repeatthis}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{repeatcount}{0}%
    \loop%
    {#3\medskip\par}%changed <<<<<<<<<<<
    \stepcounter{repeatcount}%
    \ifnum\value{repeatcount}<#2%
    {#1}%
    \repeat%        
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data1.csv}
    No|Name
    1|AAA
    2|BCA
    3|DXY
    4|AAA4
    5|BCA5
    6|DXY6
    7|AAA7
    8|BCA8
    9|DXY9
    10|XYA
    11|AAA
    12|BCA
    13|DXY
    14|AAA4
    15|BCA5
    16|DXY6
    17|AAA7
    18|BCA8
    19|DXY9
    20|XXY9
\end{filecontents}

\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{data1}{data1.csv}

\renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{red}{white}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}%  
    \parindent0pt
    
    \repeatthis{2}{%
        \DTLforeach{data1}{\dataNo=No,\dataName=Name}{%
            \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.13\textwidth}   %changed <<<<<<<<<<<
                \vspace{2mm}
                \centering 
                \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\par                    
                    \medskip
                    {\huge \dataNo}
                \smallskip
            \end{minipage}}\quad%
        }%
    }
    
\end{document}
```